# Can't upload a project to the App Store because of "Launch storyboard not found" (ERROR ITMS-90705)

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I am programming an iOS app in Swift without a storyboard.

I can run the app on a simulator and my physical device but when I tried to upload the project file to the App Store, the message below showed up and I don't know what to do.

> Launch storyboard not found. Make sure you specify the launch
>   storyboard filename without a filename extension for the key
>   UILaunchStoryboardName in the Info.plist.

Does anybody know what to do in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UILaunchStoryboardName**

Specifies the storyboard from which to generate a launch image to use for the app. See UILaunchStoryboardName for details.

> It means that your app should contain Launch Storyboard that will be
>   shown to the user when he opens the app.

Just create new storyboard => **right click on the project => New File => Choose story board**  ( name it as Launch or anything ). **Storyboard name can be anything.**

Create a View Controller and check the **is initial view controller.**

[image]

Update the name in the **launch screen file** section.

[image]

Comment: @coonie Make sure you update the launch screen storyboard to best match your app. Do not submit your app with the default launch screen.